# Notify If the Stream Continued Pass a Pipe or Instead Ended at Pipe - Node - Gulp - JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-notify, gulp-newer

**Update - The more I dig into this... the more I think it has to do with node.**

I using [gulp-newer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer) and [gulp-notify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-notify), which includes [node-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier).  When I run a tasks that doesn't produce any new files, because `newer` doesn't see any changes and jumps out of the task.  I would like to have a `notification` saying `Done - no new files`.  All it does now is end without notification.

Quick code Example:

```
gulp.task('copy', function(){
        return gulp.src('/app')
            .pipe(newer('/dist')) 
           - insert code to notify if all the files are the same or if stream ends before next pipe...
            .pipe(gulp.dest('/dist'))
            .pipe(notify({message: 'Copy task done', onLast: true}));
    });
```

Here is an example of code I've tried -

```
.pipe($.newer(path.distBase).on('end',function(){ $.nodeNotifier.notify({message:'No Files'})}))
```

**The issue being that newer always ends.  I need to know if the stream ends or continues on, I think.**

Comment: Could you show us your `path` configuration object?

Comment: @The Changed it to a string.  It's shouldn't matter for the question though, unless I am missing something.

Comment: you can try `.on('end', console.log.bind(console))` after piping into `newer` to check if the stream ever reports it is over (used to be an issue with some lesser used gulp plugins) or use `gulp-debug` to display what files are left in the stream.

Comment: @The you wrote `gulp-notifier`, but linked to `gulp-notify`, which the OP mentions in the first paragraph of the question.

Comment: @LeonAdler  I tried what you suggested and something similar with finish, but it always seems to fire.  I am also, trying to get a notification.

Comment: @LeonAdler Updated the question with an example I've tried.